# Loop to match dictionary keys from list append dictionary with associated data in other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop

I want to loop through my data and population my dictonairies with 'event' value and their corresponding 'xCordAdjusted' and 'yCordAdjusted'

Dataframe:

```
season  period  teamCode    event   goal    xCord   xCordAdjusted   yCord   yCordAdjusted   shotType    playerPositionThatDidEvent  playerNumThatDidEvent   shooterPlayerId shooterName shooterLeftRight    
2014    1            MTL    MISS    0           61             61     29              29  WRIST                             C                     51    8471976.0   David Desharnais    L  
2014    1            TOR    SHOT    0          -54             54     29             -29  BACK                              C                     42    8475098.0   Tyler Bozak         R
2014    1            TOR    SHOT    0          -40             40     32             -32  WRIST                             D                     46    8471392.0   Roman Polak         R
```

My work:

```
league_data = {};
league_data['SHOT'] = {};
league_data['SHOT']['x'] = [];
league_data['SHOT']['y'] = [];
league_data['GOAL'] = {};
league_data['GOAL']['x'] = [];
league_data['GOAL']['y'] = [];
league_data['MISS'] = {};
league_data['MISS']['x'] = [];
league_data['MISS']['y'] = [];
event_types = ['SHOT','GOAL','MISS']

for data in season_df:
    for event in event_types:
        if data in event_types:
             if 'x' in range(0,100):
                league_data[event]['x'].append(['xCordAdjusted'])
                league_data[event]['y'].append(['yCordAdjusted'])
league_data
```

Output:

```
{'SHOT': {'x': [], 'y': []},
 'GOAL': {'x': [], 'y': []},
 'MISS': {'x': [], 'y': []}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for data in season_df:` iterate on columns, not rows.
Instead, use `for index, row in season_df.iterrows()`

However, iteration on rows is **quite slow**, so if your data is quite big, you can utilize vectorization.

Also, your code looks not working as you expected.. like `if 'x' in range(0, 100)`. I re-code it on my assumption, try this.

```py
for event in event_types:
    matched_df = season_df[season_df['event'] == event]
    x_matched_list = matched_df[(0 <= matched_df['xCordAdjusted']) & (matched_df['xCordAdjusted'] <= 100)]['xCordAdjusted'].tolist()
    league_data[event]['x'] = x_matched_list # or extend
    
    y_matched_list = matched_df[(0 <= matched_df['yCordAdjusted']) & (matched_df['yCordAdjusted'] <= 100)]['yCordAdjusted'].tolist()
    league_data[event]['y'] = y_matched_list # or extend
```

But be careful with possibility of length 'xCordAdjusted' not matching with 'yCordAdjusted'

Comment: "ValueError: Lengths must match to compare" how do I fix?

Comment: can you show me more detail error message ? it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the desired information directly from the DataFrame in a vectorized fashion, instead of looping over it repeatedly:

```py
league_data = {
    'SHOT': {},
    'GOAL': {},
    'MISS': {},
}

for event in event_types:
    mask = (season_df['event'] == event) & season_df['xCord'].between(0, 100)
    x_adjusted = season_df.loc[mask, 'xCordAdjusted'].tolist()
    y_adjusted = season_df.loc[mask, 'yCordAdjusted'].tolist()
    league_data[event]['x'] = x_adjusted
    league_data[event]['y'] = y_adjusted
```

gives

```
{'GOAL': {'x': [], 'y': []},
 'MISS': {'x': [61], 'y': [-29]},
 'SHOT': {'x': [], 'y': []}
}
```

Note that I adjusted the range condition since your original code `if 'x' in range(0,100)` doesn't do what you intend because it doesn't reference your DataFrame at all.